# Query Jira for Status Change within one hour

Tags: jira, jql

I need to query Jira for Issues put "In Progress" with in an hour of time of creation.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the latest JIRA API docs](http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/), there's a search api for use with JIRA. Here is a link to the docs:

http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#id161575

This link shows details of how to issue a JQL query against the search api.

[JIRA JQL searching by date - is there a way of getting Today() (Date) instead of Now() (DateTime)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713770/jira-jql-searching-by-date-is-there-a-way-of-getting-today-date-instead-of)

Answer (score 0):

```
status = "In Progress" AND created < '1d'
```

I hope this can help you. If you wanted to see recent, simply as follow:

```
status = "In Progress" AND created < '1d' ORDER BY created DESC
```