Jira REST api error when searching for created date
I am making a RESP api call to the JIRA api, searching for reporter and project, this works correctly but if I add a "created" date I get an 'Exception: Invalid argument' error.
Working example -->
'https://jira.company.org/rest/api/2/search?jql=(reporter='joe' OR author='joe') AND (project in (prod1, prod2, prod3))'
Give error -->
'https://jira.company.org/rest/api/2/search?jql=(reporter='joe' OR author='joe') AND (project in (prod1, prod2, prod3) AND (created > 2024-06-15)) '
I have tried putting the date in different quotes and escaping double quotes but the same error occurs. Trying the query directly in Jira works.

Date formats listed in this answer should work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50876477/14072498 along with expressions like created > startOfDay(-0d)

Same Invalid argument error
